# Spring MVC : Preventing Exceptions when binding model attribute

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, xss

In my model(s) I use Numeric data types like Long, Integer etc.
When I do form post of them, but supply String, it outputs Exception stack trace, including like NumberFormatException.
How can i properly wrap this so that UI does not see the exception stack trace ?

Comment: Use a `try..catch` block

Comment: Jens, you mean in Setter of that property i use try catch ?

Comment: Yes that is what i mean.

Comment: That would not be very feasible, as I will have to do that for many properties I'm having across application. Is there any generic way to tell spring to not include the Exception Message in BindingResult ?

Comment: Maybe there is a way using aop.

Comment: any pointers you could think of? I would still like to keep the properties and the setters/getters to Numeric type.

Comment: use bean validation annotations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have a `BindingResult` argument **right after** the command argument (with `@Value` annotation) in your controller. Then you can inspect the `bindingResult` and decide what to do with the stuff that could`t be bind.

When you have that `BindingResult` argument then the controller method gets invoked, even with an binding error, and you have to handle the error yourself.

Typically it would look a bit like this example (create a user or render the user create page again):

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView create(@Valid UserCreateCommand userCreateCommand,
                           BindingResult bindingResult) {
   if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        //or some of your handling for bindingResult errors
        return new ModelAndView("user/create", userCreateCommand", userCreateCommand);
    } else {
    ...
    }
}
```

---

> But how do I differentiate the normal validation errors vs. validation errors occuring due to NumberFormatException ?

The `BindingResult` has several methods to obtain the `FieldErrors`, for example `BindingResult.getFieldErrors()`. and a `FieldError` has the property `boolean isBindingFailure()`

Comment: Ralph, I am using bindingResult.hasErrors to check for validation errors. But how do i differentiate the normal validation errors vs. validation errors occuring due to NumberFormatException ?

Comment: BindingResult.getFieldErrors().get(i).isBindingFailure()

Comment: Ralph, I am facing same error where my Bean id field is int and I am using Form:input , than send that field to controller and retrieving in it via @ModelAttribute, but getting exception: **org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'int'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "editSaveUser"].** How can i get Model object without exception? I need id as well to save in database.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display customized message for that exception you should configure Spring to use message.properties file and specify 'typeMismatch.className.propertyName' message or global message for typeMismatch.

For example (Spring 3.2): In servlet-config.xml

```
<bean id="messageSource"
class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource"
p:basename="classpath:messages/messages">
</bean>
```

In src/main/resources/messages/messages.properties

```
typeMismatch = Invalid data format!
```

In controller:

```
public String addObject(@Valid @ModelAttribute("objectForm")
ObjectForm objectForm, BindingResult result, Model model)
{
        if (result.hasErrors())
        {
            return "/addObject";
        }
    //...
}
```

In jsp:

```
<form:errors path="propertyName" cssClass="divErrorsServer" element="div" />
```

You can also use:

```
System.out.println(result.getAllErrors());
```

To see what codes you can add in messages file for that error. For example when I used String on `private Double weight` field I got those codes:

```
[typeMismatch.objectForm.weight,
typeMismatch.weight,
typeMismatch.java.lang.Double,
typeMismatch]
```